# Place static constexpr *member* variables in specific linker sections on ARM GCC (e.g. ARM m4)

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, arm, c++20

In modern C++ (C++20) with GCC and/or Clang, is there a way to specify the linker section of static constexpr **class member** variables, e.g. as in

```cpp
template<size_t N>
struct StringLiteral {
    char value[N];
};

template <StringLiteral S>
struct ConstexprStr {
    static constexpr const char[]
        value __attribute__((section("constexpr_strings")))
        = S::value;
};

// now use the address of that at runtime e.g. in a logging function as follows:
void pass_static_string_to_log_backend(const char *msg){
    // exposition only
    indicate_a_static_string_being_logged(
        reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(msg));
}

// Now we can define a log macro as follows
#define LOG(msg)                        \
   ::pass_static_string_to_log_backend( \
       ConstexprStr<msg>::value         \
   )

int main(){
   // using the above template trick, we "magically" created a 
   // global static constant from a local scope:
   LOG("hello world");
   return 0;
}
```

The attribute above seems to have no effect - the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes) explicitly that it applies to *global* variables not *local* ones, but doesn't explicitly mention (constexpr) static member variables (and I never fully wrapped my head around the details of the C++ concept of *linkage*).

The background to the question is the following:

I'm experimenting with ways to optimise logging on small, memory-constrained microcontrollers. One can for example consider not to format any messages at log-time at all, just storing the addresses of the strings as well as the variables into some binary stream.
An implementation of this idea is seen for example in the [binary_log](https://github.com/p-ranav/binary_log) library.

In many cases, the log-output is never needed on the micro-controller at all, but only at a later point off-device. Now we wonder: Why store those strings in flash at all, wasting bytes that are never going to be accessed? We just need an arbitrary number to associate with each message. The challenge is to let the compiler/linker create these numbers, as well as a listing of the corresponding strings.

If I could collect those strings in a separate section, then I could move that section outside of the flash space using the linker and strip it before creating the final image. For message re-assembly I simply store the binary of that section elsewhere and read the strings from it.

Here is my full [experiment on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ab9qa9c3E).

An alternative approach would be to create a hash of the strings at compile time and inject the strings into the debug information somehow. But that feels much less elegant, and I have yet to find a good way to store the string in the debug info. Demangling `StringLiteral<8ul>{char [8]{(char)119, (char)97, (char)114, (char)110, (char)32, (char)123, (char)125}}` doesn't feel like a good way.

Comment: I think what you are asking is pretty straightforward, except that I don't understand why templates need to be involved (or `constexpr`, for that matter). You can declare `__attribute__((section("constexpr_strings"))) const char HELLO_MESSAGE[] = "Hello World";` and `const char * const str_ptr = HELLO_MESSAGE;`

Comment: It is straightforward if templates aren't involved, but they are needed. Your code needs to be written at namespace scope, which precludes automatic generation by the compiler e.g. from a logging macro. On the other hand, a logging macro can (in C++20) wrap the string in a NTTP or a constexpr lambda to create a unique, constant, static symbol containing the string. Then, you need at least `inline` (implied by `constexpr`) to allow it to be initialised inplace. Constexpr ensures at compile-time that you really end-up with a constant in the binary, rather than some code being executed at start.

Comment: extended the minimal example to highlight why templates are needed. have a look at example on godbolt as well.

Comment: It is a well-known bug. Please, check [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70435), [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88061) or [this one](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94342)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the bug pointed at the comments is at play here - however there are I think two other issues.

The first is that the section attribute is put to template class members and not to concrete instantiations of data. Because of this the compiler doesn't know *what* data it should put into the section as the section attribute is not sticky. So if you take your code example and you do something like in the code below it will work as you expect for the `Debug` `StringLiteral`:

```
// All your code upto before your main function

static constexpr StringLiteral Debug __attribute__((section("SEB"))) = "debug {}";

int main() {
    int cnt=0;

    logger1.debug<Debug>(cnt++);

    // Your other code from main
}
```

In effect you have to take all your actual `constexpr` strings and apply the section to each one individually.

The second problem is trickier. When you compile your code using `-O2`, as you do now, even with my modification - the string will be completely optimized away. It will not appear in any section. Try the code with `-O0` and you will see the `SEB` section in the output.

Changing the above declaration/Definition of `Debug` in the following way should work even with optimization (although it is not pretty).

```
extern const char S_Debug[] __attribute__((section("SEB"))) = "debug {}";;
static constexpr StringLiteral Debug = S_Debug;
```

Here is the modified example in [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/W85csrqcG)

Comment: I do not think that this assessment is correct. While there is of course no standard definition of the effect of non-standard attributes, the obvious interpretation would be that an attribute on a member of a template would apply to all instantiations respectively. This is definitely the case for the standard attribute `[[nodiscard]]`. Furthermore, as explained in the issues pointed out by @Fusho, clang does apply the section attribute as well, as can be seen in a slightly massaged form of the above example: https://godbolt.org/z/x4YWY4rEW.

Comment: Neither do I think that optimisations are a fundamental problem, as long as the address of the string is actually used somewhere in the code (and there is also `__attribute__((used))`). Therefore, if @Fusho writes an answer indicating that this is considered a bug in GCC, I'll award the bounty to them.

Comment: @burnpanck No worries about the bounty. That is not the reason I wrote the answer. The description of the problem interested me. However if you are working with GCC and need to place the strings in the specified section then the solution I presented will work, Cheers